# Random Permutation and counting how many positions a[i] < a[i+1] in permutation

Tags: java, permutation

The first line contains the number of marathons `t < 100`. Each marathon is specified by three lines. The first line contains the number of runners `1 < n <= 40000`. The second line is a permutation of the starting numbers  `1,...,n` which represents the order in which the runners passed the starting line. Finally, the third line is a permutation which represents the finishing order. For each marathon output one line which contains the minimal number of overtakings that have happend during the race.

So for example

[image: Input Output]

I really don't know how I can create a random permutation `1 < n` and how to find out then how many overtakings took place. For the latter I would check how many numbers are bigger than the next, i.e. if `4 > 3` then I increase an int `overtaking++;`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MarathonMovement {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner NoM = new Scanner(System.in); // Number of marathons
       int t = NoM.nextInt();

       Scanner NoR = new Scanner(System.in); // First line: Number of runners
       int n = NoR.nextInt();

       // Second line: Permutation of starting numbers representing the order in which the runners passed the starting line

       // Third line: Permutation which represents finishing order

        int overtakings = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           if {
               // logic
               overtakings++;
           }
        }

       for(int x = 0; x < t; x++){
          System.out.println("at least" + overtakings + " overtaking(s)");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why 3rd example's answer is **21**?

Comment: If you want to generate a random number between 1...n then you can use int num = (int) (n * Math.random()). Not exactly sure how you expect to make a logical series of overtakings from a pseudo-random sequence of numbers though

Comment: please post text rather than an image

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Because 7 is also greater than 5 etc. and 4 is greater than 2, 1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question (generate a random permutation), you can use the method Collections.shuffle:

```
    List<Integer> start = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        start.add(i + 1);
    }
    List<Integer> finish = new ArrayList<>(start);
    Collections.shuffle(finish);
```

To count the overtakings:

```
    int overtakings = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (finish.get(i) < finish.get(i-1)) {
            ++overtakings;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this task correctly, then this is my solution:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int t = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            int n = scan.nextInt();
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            Set<String> uniqueOvertaking = new HashSet<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                arr[j] = scan.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int val = scan.nextInt();

                if (arr[j] != val)
                    uniqueOvertaking.add(Math.min(arr[j], val) + "->" + Math.max(arr[j], val));
            }

            int res = uniqueOvertaking.size() == n ? uniqueOvertaking.size() - 1 : uniqueOvertaking.size();
            System.out.println("at least " + res + " overtaking(s)");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
at least 1 overtaking(s)
at least 5 overtaking(s)
at least 3 overtaking(s)
```